# syntax error, unexpected 'endforeach' (T_ENDFOREACH), expecting end of file. Alguém faz ideia do por que desse erro?

Tags: php, laravel

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Listagem de Produtos</h1>
   <table>
        <?php foreach($produtos as $p) ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?php $p->nome ?></td>
        <td><?php $p->valor ?></td>
        <td><?php $p->descricao ?></td>
        <td><?php $p->valor ?></td>
     </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Faltou `:` em `foreach($produtos as $p)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Listagem de Produtos</h1>
   <table>
        <?php foreach($produtos as $p): ?>
     <tr>
        <td><?=$p->nome;?></td>
        <td><?=$p->valor;?></td>
        <td><?=$p->descricao;?></td>
        <td><?=$p->valor;?></td>
     </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Tente o código acima. O código estava faltando o `:` no encerramento do `$p)`.
Simplifiquei seu `$p->valor`.

Para exibir um resultado de uma variável na tela você deve utilizar no PHP `echo` ou `print`.

A simplificação feita no seu código foi a impressão do valor na coluna da tabela `<?=$variavel;?>` exibe o valor da variável direto na tela.

[Mais informações sobre foreach na documentação do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)